# Add a variable (name of the sheet) in a cell function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 3 different Sheets named as consecutive dates: 2017-02-03, 2017-02-04, 2017-02-05, ...

In each one, I want a resume of the day before, which is in the cell G1 (in each Sheet).

So I want something like this:

```
G2 =(Name of this sheet -1)!G1
```

So, if, for example, I am in sheet 2017-02-04 I will have in G2 the value of G1 in the 2017-02-03 Sheet

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you looking for a Formula?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a formula

Comment: @Iván is it okay if the solution uses Google Apps Script?

Comment: I am not a Formula expert, but this doesn't seem possible based on the [list of available functions](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en). It would be possible with a custom function.

Answer (score 0):

This can only be done with a custom function, not just a formula. I've created a custom function below that can be called like this: `=GETLASTSHEETVALUE("G1")` Note the quote around G1, they are important. This will find the sheet just before the current sheet and return the value of the cell you ask for. This *will not* work with ranges, only a single cell.

Add the following code to the spreadsheet's script editor (Menu 'Tools' > click 'Script editor') then save and close.

```
function GETLASTSHEETVALUE(input){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var name = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  for(var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++){
    if(name === sheets[i].getName()) return sheets[i-1].getRange(input).getValue();
  }
  return "Error";
}
```